# \tableofcontents[ISSUES]

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Hello TeX/LaTeX/Beamer colleagues,

There is a prob I could not solve. I'm preparing a 2 hours class, so my toc is really heavy.
5 Sections, some of them with several subsections.

I already have the following outline at the beginning:

OUTLINE

1 Section One

2 Section Two
.
.
.
5 Section Five.

However, running the presentation,  at the beginning of each section and subsection appears the dense toc. All sections + all subsections.... frightful!

What I want is, starting either a section or a subsection, to project a clean viewgraph containing ONLY the current section, highlighting the current subsection and shading the others (subsections of the current section...)

Is possible to do that?

In advance I thank you very much!

Best

Physics is love!

Comment: Dividing the document in parts using `\part{}` solves your problem? If you want you can set up the section counter to not be reseted when changing the parts.

Answer (score 4):

`beamer` offers you this possibility out of the box, using the `sectionstyle`, `subsectionstyle` keys for the `\tableofcontents`.

If you want, at the beginning of each each section, to have a table of contents showing only the current section with its subsections, all you need is

```
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
  subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
```

so, the following lines

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
  subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
]
\end{frame}
}
```

will do exactly what you need. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
  subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The ToC for the first section:

[image]

The ToC for the second section:

[image]

The ToC for the third section:

[image]

If what you want is to have, at the beginning of each subsection, a ToC showing the current section and subsection and all other subsections for the current section shaded, then the specification would change to

```
currentsection,
sectionstyle=show/hide,
subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
```

And the ToC will be produced using

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
  subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
]
\end{frame}
}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,
  sectionstyle=show/hide,
  subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection One Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Two Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three One}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Two}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}
\subsection{Test Subsection Three Three}
\begin{frame} test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An image of the ToC for the second subsection of the first section:

[image]

An image of the ToC for the third subsection of the third section:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this should solve the problem.Have a look at this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\beamer@sectionintoc}{\vskip1.5em}{\vskip0.5em}{}{}
\makeatother

\title[Short Title]{My very long title that doesn't fix into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}


\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 6}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 6}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 7}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 7}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 8}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 8}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

These are sample images of the part of the presentation slides.I hope this is what is required....

Answer (score 1):

If you split you document in parts, the contents also will be like.

So, redefining the `\section` you don't need to insert parts by hand.

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\part{}\oldsection{#1}}
```

Using

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}
```

the result will be like this (note *Topic 2*):

[image]

Full code (copied from @subham soni):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\part{}\oldsection{#1}}

\title[Short Title]{My very long title that doesn't fix into the footer}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Intro}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Welcome}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 1}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 2}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Red}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Red}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Green}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Green}
...
\end{frame}

\subsection{Blue}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blue}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 3}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 3}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 4}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 4}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 5}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 5}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 6}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 6}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 7}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 7}
...
\end{frame}

\section{Topic 8}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Topic 8}
...
\end{frame}

\section{The end}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{The end}
End of file :-)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```